# Sending JSON request to hipchat

Tags: java, json

I am making something for my HipChat room but for it to work i have to send a JSON request of:

```
POST /v1/rooms/message?format=json&auth_token=token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.hipchat.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 138

room_id=10&from=Alerts&message=A+new+user+signed+up
```

So far i have this:

```
public static void send(String send){
    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

  try{
      url = new URL("http://api.hipchat.com");
      conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "138");

      conn.setUseCaches (false);
      conn.setDoInput(true);
      conn.setDoOutput(true);

      DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
              conn.getOutputStream ());
      wr.writeBytes (send);
      wr.flush ();
      wr.close ();


      InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      String line;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
      while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          response.append(line);
          response.append('\r');
      }
      rd.close();
      System.out.println(line);
  }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }finally{
      if(conn != null) {
          conn.disconnect();
      }
  }
}
```

But in the console it just returns `null`. How would i go about sending the above JSON request?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any JSON involved. What is a json request? Do you mean the response will contain json?

Comment: Thats just the sending method, Above it is the Format and the bottom line is the JSON it give me on: https://www.hipchat.com/docs/api/method/rooms/message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you loop here

```
while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
```

your `line` variable is replaced with the value returned by `rd.readLine()`. The last time it loops, that method call will return `null`. That's why `line` is `null`.

I'm going to assume you wanted to print out `response`.

Comment: Ah yes forgot about that :)